# Android Studio cannot find SDK

Tags: android-studio-2.3

i was using android studio 2.3.3 in my previous hard disk, android studio working fine, but when i change hard disk, and again install android studio in new hard disk, it installed but it cannot find sdk, error messege is please specify Android SDK location,
i gave its location also by going in    configure> Project Defaults> Project Structure
i gave this location where SDK is exist
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

but still it just checking availability and nothing happens
please help

[this is a snap of my project structure window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTWOr.png)

Comment: You probably want to check Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK

Comment: Also, you should clarify what you mean by "change hard disk". You almost certainly want to reinstall Android Studio if you have replaced a fixed disk on a system where it was installed previously.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time you`re running Android Studio and it keeps asking for the SDK, do the following:

1. It should have opened a project already, so go to "File > Close project" and close all opened projects
2. Underneath that screen you should see a different wizard saying it's still missing the SDK, and it will help you install it
3. Do the usual "Next, next, finish" setup process
4. Open Android Studio again, open up a project and let it try to compile
5. It should ask if you accept the SDK's License Agreement, and if you do check "accept" then "next", and finally "finish"

Now reopen your Android Studio and it should be fixed! :)